# Call widget's own function outside it

Tags: function, flutter, statefulwidget

I have this a stateful widget which could be in two situations, the first one is a Container with a first text in it, for example, "Register", the second one is a different colored container with a different text, for example "confirm". The Problem is that the transition between these two situations is done using an animation and it's not an on-the-fly logic for example:

```
color: isSituation1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.red.
```

it's actually something like this:

```
color: Color.lerp(Colors.blue, Colors.red, _animation1.value)
```

and I have a function which runs when the user taps on the container which forwards the animation controller, like so:

```
_controller1.forward()
```

and this is a widget called let's say Button1

So in My HomePage stateful widget I have another button which should trigger the inverse process in the Button1 widget, so it would be:

```
_controller1.reverse()
```

I tried creating a function in the Button1 widget but then I cannot run it from outside. How could I do it if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to call methods of your CustomWidget from another widget. You can define ControllerClass that you will emit  an instance when you create a new instance of your CustomWidget. This ControllerClass instance will hold the functions of your CustomWidget and you will be able to call them from outside.

By example a class that is a modal rounded progressbar that can be showed and hided from outise with a controller class. In this example a controller class is called ProgressBarHandler. I don't know if it is a better and the right approach but works.

```
class ModalRoundedProgressBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _textMessage;
  final double _opacity;
  final Color _color;
  final Function _handlerCallback;

  ModalRoundedProgressBar({
    @required Function handleCallback(ProgressBarHandler handler), //callback to get a controller
    String message = "",
    double opacity = 0.7,
    Color color = Colors.black54,
  })  : _textMessage = message,
        _opacity = opacity,
        _color = color,
        _handlerCallback = handleCallback;

  @override
  State createState() => _ModalRoundedProgressBarState();
}

class _ModalRoundedProgressBarState extends State<ModalRoundedProgressBar> {
  bool _isShowing = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // init controller. 
    ProgressBarHandler handler = ProgressBarHandler();
    handler.show = this.show;
    handler.dismiss = this.dismiss;
    widget._handlerCallback(handler); // callback call.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_isShowing) return Stack();

    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Opacity(
            opacity: widget._opacity,
            child: ModalBarrier(
              dismissible: false,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),

          Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                Text(widget._textMessage),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void show() {
    setState(() => _isShowing = true);
  }

  void dismiss() {
    setState(() => _isShowing = false);
  }
}

  class ProgressBarHandler { 
      Function show; // will point to widget show method
      Function dismiss; // will point to another method.
   }


// ...in another external widget you can do...
// ... code your things and:
var controller;
var progressBar = ModalRoundedProgressBar(
  handleCallback: ((handler){ controller = handler; } ),);

//calling show method with controller
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () { controller.show(); }
);


//calling dismiss method with controller
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () { controller.dismiss(); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you probably don't want to do that. You should either provide the `AnimationController` from the parent or structure your app to prevent such behaviors. Anyway, if you still want to go this way, here you have it.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  VoidCallback _reverseAnimation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Reverse animation'),
            onPressed: () => _reverseAnimation(),
          ),
          Button1((controller) => _reverseAnimation = controller),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Button1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<VoidCallback> callback;
  Button1(this.callback);
  _Button1State createState() => _Button1State();
}

class _Button1State extends State<Button1> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _someAnimationController;

  void _reverseAnimation() {
    _someAnimationController?.reverse();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.callback != null) {
      widget.callback(_reverseAnimation);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Start animation'),
        onPressed: () => _someAnimationController.forward(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```